# Swift 2 toInt() not working

Tags: ios, swift

I just upgraded to Swift 2.0 and am unsure as to why this line of code isn't working.I know toInt() was remove in Swift 2.0 but I can't figure how to update this line of code so it will work in Swift 2.0. Any suggestions?

Old line:

```
followers.setTitle((followers.currentTitle!.toInt()! - 1).description, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I tried this line with no success:

```
followers.setTitle((followers.currentTitle!.Int()! + 1).description, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: It might be more efficient to declare an `Int` variable for the follower counter to do the math and update the title with `String(counter)`.

Answer (score 3):

Read the error message

> `toInt()` is unavailable: Use `Int()` initializer

means

```
Int(followers.currentTitle!)!
```

Comment: Don't encourage them to implicitly unwrap things. Before you know it, they will post another question about it :p

Comment: That is irrelevant for the question.  `currentTitle` could be safely integer convertible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
followers.setTitle((Int(followers.currentTitle!)! + 1).description, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```